# How to calculate and store (ArcMap) slope on huge mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, slope, large-datasets, mosaic-dataset

I have a huge raster dataset stored in a geoDB (DHM with 2m resolution for all of Switzerland), uncompressed size ~75 GB. I want to use the ArcMap Slope tool (or another tool would also work) to calculate slopes for the whole country.

**How do I go about processing such a huge dataset?**

Is it possible to process this "tile by tile" (since it is already mosaiced, there should be some tiling?). Also unclear to me: The result will be of similar size... what would be an efficient way to store the result? I don't have write access on the DB it is coming from, but I could create a new DB.

Comment: Is it a Mosaic Dataset or a single image? Creating a raster function for the slope in a referenced mosaic dataset may be easier than processing the entire image.

Comment: it is a mosaic dataset (that's what it says in Properties) - I do not know how it is stored in the database however